# Move dataset from root to folder in VS solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, solution-explorer

Im just trying to organise a pretty large solution in VS2010.

Id like to place my datasets into a sub folder of the root but when I do I get a string of errors, how can I move them **and** update any reference to them?

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you move a DataSet in Visual Studio, Visual Studio automatically updates the namespace in the DataSet to include the folder name at the end.  You can go into each DataSet and remove the last/added part of the namespace.  That will fix your errors.

Answer (score 0):

It's not beautifully flexible but you could use a Find & Replace on all files in the solution?